# Build Gradle JAR without dependencies

Tags: gradle, jar, dependencies, command, line

From command line, I need to build an executable jar *without* dependencies.
The current "gradle build" command gives me a jar with dependencies.

Couldn't find this on StackOverflow. If it's a duplicate question, point me there. Thanks.

Comment: please provide at least a brief description of your project:  is it a java library or java application? a springboot app maybe?  and what plugins are you using?

Comment: Java Application. Springboot app. Plugins: 'java', 'application', 'spring-boot'. Gradle 1.8

Comment: I proposed an answer with explanation and solution. let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have SpringBoot plugin enabled, the default behavior is to build an executable jar (fat-jar) containing all dependencies, through the`bootJar` task.

You can still generate a single "standard" jar if you need, this is explained in the documentation : [Spring Boot Gradle plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal)

```
jar {
    enabled = true
}
bootJar {
    classifier = 'boot'
}
```